# Verification of credentials in Hyperledger-Indy

Tags: identity, hyperledger-indy

I was goin through the documentation of INDY , in the example with alice,faber and thrift , the part where the credentials are validated is mentioned as

> Acme got all the requested attributes. Now Acme wants to check the
>   Validity Proof. To do it Acme first must get every Credential Schema
>   and corresponding Credential Definition for each identifier presented
>   in the Proof, the same way that Alice did it. Now Acme has everything
>   to check Job-Application Proof from Alice.

Where can I find more details on this validation process ? At this moment acme has apply_job_prrof sent by the Alice agent.

1. Has this apply job proof ,been signed by Alice ?
2. So Identification information ,the Transcript details , ( the actual
   details are fetched from the blockchain by alice and she just adds
   it to the payload ) ?
3. How does the validation actually work ? What stops Alice from
   fabricating a wrong payload?

Answer (score 1):

Indy implements the Aries approach to credential verification. See the following Aries RFC standard:

https://github.com/hyperledger/aries-rfcs/tree/master/features/0037-present-proof

The Indy anoncreds design is detailed here:

https://github.com/hyperledger/indy-sdk/tree/master/docs/design/002-anoncreds

The step-by-step example is here:

https://github.com/hyperledger/indy-sdk/tree/master/docs/how-tos/negotiate-proof

And the cryptographic details are in Hyperledger Ursa:

https://github.com/hyperledger/ursa-docs/tree/master/specs/anoncreds1